# Which 64-bit server image to use for Intel Pentium G3220?

Tags: server, system-installation, 64-bit

Soon, I'll have to install an Ubuntu Server on a computer with a Intel Pentium G3220 64-bit instruction set processor. So I'm looking at the current LTS Server edition, 14.04.4. However, the page says:

http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.4/release/ (via http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads then "Other images"):

> There are three images available, each for a different type of computer:
>
> - 64-bit Mac (AMD64) server install image
>     Choose this to take full advantage of computers based on the AMD64 or EM64T architecture (e.g., Athlon64, Opteron, EM64T Xeon, Core 2). ...
> - Mac (PowerPC) and IBM-PPC (POWER5) server install image
>     For Apple Macintosh G3, G4, and G5 computers, including iBooks and PowerBooks as well as older IBM OpenPower 7xx machines.
> - PowerPC64 Little-Endian server install image
>     For POWER8 Little-Endian computers, such as Power Systems S8xxL/LC Linux-only servers.

Ok, I don't get it - which one of these is applicable for an Intel Pentium-processor based system? As far as I know, Pentium is not AMD, nor is it PPC?

Comment: Thanks @muru - indeed, that question explains it all, cheers!